# Simple Ajax request to echo data from textfile onto HTML getting GET 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

### Problem

I'm new to AJAX request so I believe I might be making a simple mistake, but whenever I want to run my script using an AJAX request I get a `500 (Internal Server Error)`

[image]
[image]

Basically what I want to happen is if the user presses the `#show-all` button I will run a `showall.php` script that reads tasks from a `data.txt` file and prints the tasks in HTML on the webpage.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

PS: Line 24 refers to `$.ajax({` and Line 27 refers to `console.log("Error: " + error);`

### Code

*Ajax request*

```
 $("#show-all").on("click", function () {
    console.log("button pressed");
    $.ajax({
        url: '../p2/showall.php'
        , error: function (error) {
            console.log("Error: " + error);
        }
        , success: function (response) {
            console.log("Success: " + response);
        }
    });
});
```

*showall.php*

```
<?php 
    $filename = 'data.txt';
    include('file.php');
    include('add.php');
    $tasks = read_file($filename);
    foreach($tasks as $task){
        echo_task($task);
    }
?>
```

*file.php*

```
<?php
//Write task element to file
function write_file($filename, $task){
    $arr = array($task->title, $task->due_date, $task->priority, $task->course, $task->note);
    $line = implode("\t", $arr);
    $line .= "\n";
    
    $file_pointer = fopen($filename, 'a' );
    if ( ! $file_pointer ) { echo( 'error' ); exit; }
    $error = fputs($file_pointer,$line);
    fclose($file_pointer);
}

//Read file $filename and return array of Tasks
function read_file($filename){
    $lines = file($filename);
    if(!$lines){
        print( 'error' ); 
        exit; 
    }
    
    $tasks = array();
    foreach($lines as $line){
        //Assume every entry should have notes
        $arr = explode("\t", $line);
        //Assume notes should not have \n in it
        $arr[4] = str_replace("\n", "", $arr[4]);
        $task = new Task($arr[0], $arr[1], $arr[2], $arr[3], $arr[4]);
        $tasks[] = $task;
    }
    
    return $tasks;
}
?>
```

*add.php*

```
<?php 
//Returns true if text field input isset & not empty string, otherwise returns false & echos issue to use
function validText($field){
    if(isset($_POST['add'])){
        if(isset($_POST[$field])){
            if($_POST[$field] !== ''){
                return true;
            }
            
            echo "<h3 class='error'>*Task $field cannot be empty</h3>";
            return false;
        }
        echo "<h3 class='error'>*Task $field must be set</h3>";
        return false;
    }
    
    return true;
}

//Return task from form elements
function task_from_form(){
    if(isset($_POST['add']) && isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['note'])){     
        if($_POST['title'] !== '' && $_POST['note'] !== ''){
            $title = $_POST['title'];
            $note = $_POST['note'];
            $title_trim = trim($title);
            $note_trim = trim($note);
            $title_html = htmlentities($title_trim);
            $note_html = htmlentities($note_trim);

            $due_date = $_POST['due-date'];
            $priority = $_POST['priority'];
            $course = $_POST['course'];
            $course_space = str_replace("-", " ", $course);
            
            $task = new Task($title_html, $due_date, $priority, $course_space, $note_html);
            
            return $task; 
        }
    }
}

//Echo task
function echo_task($task){
    echo "<div class='task row'>
            <div class='task-title row'>
                <button type='button' class='checkbox col'><span class='icon-checkbox-box' aria-hidden='true'></span></button>
                <h1 class='col'>{$task->title}</h1>
                <div class='task-info'>
                    <h2 class='due-date col task-date'>{$task->due_date}</h2>
                    <button type='button' class='priority {$task->priority} col'><span class='icon-circle' aria-hidden='true'></span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='task-details'>
                <div class='row'>
                    <h2 class='col'>{$task->course}</h2> </div>
                <div class='row'>
                    <p class='note col'>{$task->note}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>";
}

?>
```

Comment: 500 => check your logs if you haven't already.

Comment: Try to go to the link which is giving 500 error to check if it exists or not. Maybe the relative path you gave in ajax call is not working.

Comment: @Fred-ii- rightt! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is not an ajax issue. If you visit `http://localhost:8888/p2/showall.php` I think you will get the same 500 error. Try to check your server, if its a php issue, create a html file to return same content as you want, will be easier to debug.